# What is splitindex.exe.stackdump and why does changing the name of my document fix my splitindex problem?

Tags: indexing

I recently made some major changes to my custom document class. These changes were mainly visually but not functionally. However, splitindex has started making trouble and I cant figure out why.

Here is the thing:

My document administration_manual.tex won´t compile its index. If I run splitindex, texworks displays

```
 splitindex 2808 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to splitindex.exe.stackdump
```

If I rename administration_manual.tex to administration_manual_2.tex, it compiles the index without any problems. It seems like the problem is related the name but ist still soemhow arbitrary. A couple of days ago I managed to "fix" this problem by simply rebooting my computer. Also, the problem still remains after deleting all temp. files. I have a bunch of documents and each of them works just fine. Still, it looks like texworks, splitindex.exe or maybe even Windows is having issues with the name.

Why is that and what can I do to compile the index of administration_manual.tex? I would like to keep the name since it has multiple dependencies.

MME:
I know i should post an MME, but this time I dont think it will help. The ability to compile the index seems to be influenced by the name of the document.

Update:

Her is something funny, which indicates that texworks itself might be the problem:
If I use Gradle (most of our documents etc. are automatically build using Gradle), I am able to compile an index, disregarding the document/ file name.

Comment: Just a guess.  But you may have stray files of the old name lying around: aux files, and other files related to indices, that contain bad data.  Deleting those auxiliary files under the old name might allow recompilation under it.

Comment: I remove all temporary files from the build process with a batch file searching through all folders. But you are right, this error sounds like one of latex´ typical "bad data" errors. I really don´t get it. I just managed to compile my document by just adding "a_2". It uses the same .tex files, diretories etc. as the original document, which won´t compile.

Answer (score 1):

Generated stackdump files are not related to a documentclass. Actually, they are pretty much randon, caused by some problem with cgywin (splitindex.exe needs that) and texworks.

1. Generating a document using a batch file or gradle will not produce an error. I was able  to comple all indices using gradle and batch files.
2. The document name is related to the problem. Changing the document name will "fix" the problem.
3. Deleting all temporary files is always a good approach, but this time it won´t help.
4. Sometimes, simply restarting your computer will fix the problem.
5. Texworks does not cause the problem, but is part of it. As an example: I can´t compile indice for texta.tex using texworks, but I can complile indices for textb.tex. However, I can compile indices for texta.tex with texworks, If I use a different jobname (e.g. to select the language). Either way, I am able to compile all indices using a batch file or gradle.